# SwiftUI App works fine in simulator, but not in preview

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

I'm trying to get preview working in Xcode. Just a simple test app written in Swift. Grabs rows from a Realm database and lists them.

It works fine when I build/run in the simulator but none of the data shows in the ContentView_Preview.

[App in Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY78h.png)
[App in Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAMQi.png)

Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

struct HeaderView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
            Text("Time Spent").font(.largeTitle)
            Text("or waisted...").font(.headline)
        }
    }
}

struct GroupListView: View {
    @ObservedResults(TaskGroup.self) var taskGroups
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            // Nothing from here shows in the preview.. but shows fine in the simulator
            List(taskGroups) {
                Text("Group: " + $0.name)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Task Groups (\(taskGroups.count))")
            // Grrr
        }
    }
}

struct FooterView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(" Grr.. Preview isn't working.")
            Spacer()
            Text("Simulator works fine though.")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HeaderView()
            GroupListView()
            FooterView()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I've searched for hours and tried various different suggestions. No luck. Any help would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your preview it's likely that `taskGroups` is empty. You could verify this by sticking something like

```
if taskGroups.isEmpty {
    Text("test")
}
```

For your preview you should inject some placeholder content. Depending on how Realm works there may be a mechanism to do this already, or you may need to create an abstraction that allows you to do this.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer made me look more closely at my model. I was adding data to my DB all wrong lol. 

I've been out of the game for a bit and I'm still waiting for that "it all came flooding back" moment.